# Get value for a column from another another in other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model having a column profile_id and a Profile model having primary key column id, after the create method of profile has done running, I want the profile_id column to get the value of id from profile model. I know I can do this in the after_filter method, But what should I write in the method ?

Comment: you should structure better your question, i cant understand it

Comment: There is column in User model profile_id and column in profile mode id, after running the create action of profile controller, I want to assign the id of profile to the corresponding profile_id of User model

Comment: so profile has_many users? and user belongs to profile?

Comment: User has_one profile and profile belongs_to User

Comment: If user has ome profile, you don't need profile_id in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a profile belongs_to User and a User has_one profile de foreign key should be in the Profile model

so, profile model has user_id field

in the create method of profile you could do something like this

```
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
    @profile.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile , notice: 'profile was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

or isntead of this:

```
 @profile.user_id = current_user.id
```

you can

```
 @profile.user_id = params[:user_id]
```

if you send the id through the params

Then you can access it through relations like this:

@profile.user.name
@profile.user.email
or
current_user.profile.name

Comment: I created a new after_filter method for create and added this current_user.update_attribute(:profile_id, @profile.id) and it worked for me